# code to create a geometry kml element with coordinates

Tags: kml, google-fusion-tables, markerclusterer, coordinate-transformation

I have a fusion table : 1hxNUdyIjqYRyv9wFhLcNzGyC-a8lcOlrPFEVB7oR with address. I want to use marker cluster. For this, I need to get coordinates of this address.
It's possible to create kml geometry ?

I've try to download my table in kml and open it with google earth then save in kml again. But when I create a table with this, he doesn't work very well..some coordinates are missing..

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't download these coordinates, they have been geocoded internally.

You can only download data that have been stored in the table(all you see in the [rows-view](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1hxNUdyIjqYRyv9wFhLcNzGyC-a8lcOlrPFEVB7oR#rows:id=1)).